# Every time I open a LibreOffice document, it is blank!

Tags: libreoffice

Help: Every time I open a LibreOffice document, it is blank but I can open files in word office format.

When I open any LibreOffice it is blank! I realized that the data is in the files because I can copy/paste to my google drive and open it correctly from google drive using Firefox. If then I download it to my laptop and try to open it as a LibreOffice document it is blank, but If I download it as a word office document it opens correctly!

I also created a document in LibreOffice, saved it, close LO, and reopen. Same result: it opens like a new blank document, without any of the info previously saved.

I tryed to remove all LibreOffice apps so I can reinstall them but I can't. I get the message that I must use dpkg manualy <<configure -a>> to correct the problem. I have no idea what this means.

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Lenovo. Ryzen 7.

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: I mean it opens as it was a new blank document. 
For example, the original doc could have, lets say, 20 pages but now if i open the file will only by one blank page. As if was absolutely empty, as a new doc.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you boot an Ubuntu 20.04 LiveUSB, and enter the "Try Ubuntu" environment, can you reproduce the problem with your files?

Comment: Please edit your question and remove "Help" from your title. It is not useful to learn what the question is about. What happens if you create a document on LO, then save it, then close LO then reopen the document: is it also blank? This question to see whether the problem is limited to files from Google or not. Test, and include the results of the test in your question: use "edit". You also have a problem with your package management: you will need to correct that asap.

Comment: Vanadium: question edited. Yes, reopens blank.
How can I fix the package problem you mentioned?

Comment: Try running the command line `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: Thanks. I did and I got a list of messages (my language is spanish so maybe doesn't make much sence to copy them).
Most of them are like "problems in configuration. LO math or ktk3, or writer, gnome depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:6.4.7 - 0ubuntu0.20.04.2); but:
 libreoffice-core' version in system is 1:6.4.7-0ubuntu0.20.04.1.
Does this makes any sense?
Thanks so much

Comment: @user535733 It works ok if I boot from a LiveUSB.

Comment: So the problem is not LibreOffice, and it's not your files. Seems you have narrowed the problem to something wrong specifically with your install of LibreOffice. Looks like you also have version dependency problems. Uninstall all of your LibreOffice packages and then reinstall them from the Ubuntu repositories. If you encounter problems, post complete output (not snippets, not summaries) in your Question above (not in comments).